# ¿Cómo cambiar de orden las columnas en SQL?

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla que aparece columna 1, columna 2, columna 3 y columna 4.
La quiero juntar con una tabla que tiene columna 1, columna 3, columna 2 y columna 4.

¿cómo puede cambiar el lugar de una de las columnas?

Comment: pues cambialas de lugar en el select....

Comment: El orden es irrelevante.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes esta consulta

```
select campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4 from tabla
```

Tu puedes poner el orden que quieras desde el mismo `select`

solo es que decidas tu el orden y lo organices, asi

```
 select campo2,campo1,campo4 ,campo3 from tabla
```

Esto no afecta en nada la calidad de los datos ni perjudica la ejecucion de la consulta solo visualmente cambian de lugar